# How can I create a Python function dynamically which takes a specified number of arguments?

Tags: python, python-2.7, runtime

I create a function dynamically this way:

```
def create_function(value):
    def _function():
        print value
return _function

f1 = create_func(1)
f1()
```

which works fine and prints '1'.

but my problem is slightly different, say there is a variable called no_of_arguments which contains the number of arguments the function that is being returned (_function() ) takes.

```
def create_function():
    no_of_arguments = int(raw_input()) #provided by user
    def _function(a,b,c,....):
```

'this function has to accept a certain number of arguments, specified in the variable no_of_arguments'

```
        #do something here
return _function

f1 = create_func()
f1(a,b,c......)
```

Comment: Perhaps you should explain what you're *really* after...

Comment: I don't understand what you really want, but there are `*args` and `**kwargs` keywords for functions with arbitrary parameters in Python.  May be they will be helpfull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function can be defined as taking any (minimum) number of arguments by preceding one with a `*`, which will then result in the name being bound to a tuple containing the appropriate arguments.

```
def foo(a, b, *c):
  print a, b, c

foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

You will need to limit/check the number of values passed this way yourself though.

Answer (score 1):

Use `*` in the function arguments to make it accept any number of positional arguments.

```
def func(*args):
    if len(args) == 1:
       print args[0]
    else:
       print args
...        
>>> func(1)
1
>>> func(1,2)
(1, 2)
>>> func(1,2,3,4)
(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`*args`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists):

```
def create_function():
    no_of_arguments = int(raw_input()) #provided by user
    def _function(*args):
        if len(args) == no_of_arguments:
            dostuff()
        else:
            print "{} arguments were not given!".format(no_of_arguments)
    return _function
```

Running it as an example:

```
>>> f1 = create_function()
4 # The input
>>> f1('hi','hello','hai','cabbage')
>>> f1('hey')
4 arguments were not given!
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understood, you need to pass different number of arguments to the function
You can pass different number of arguments using * like that:

```
def create_function():
    no_of_arguments = (argList) #tuple of arguments
    def _function(*argList):
```